# Azure AKS Traefik TLS Certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, azure-aks, traefik

i am trying to get TLS with K8s running.

I have created a simple Azure AKS Service and deployed Traefik by HELM (helm install traefik traefik/traefik)

After that step I deployed a simple WHOAMI-Container, with its Service and Ingress

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: whoami
  labels: 
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whoami-container
        image: containous/whoami
        ports: 
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: whoami-srv

spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: websecure
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.mydomain.de
      secretName: wildcardcert
  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.de
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: whoami-srv
            port:
              number: 80
```

I can reach the WHOAMI by opening Http://test.mydomain.de. If I open HTTPS://test.mydomain.de I can see the right certificate but I still get a "404 page not found"

Any tips from your site? I trying back and forth a couple of times :)

Thanks!

Comment: Anything in the traefik logs when you hit your service and get a 404?

Comment: kubectl logs traefik-5db6d78d4-z26s2 -n kube-system --since-time 2021-07-12T17:08:46Z

there are no logs after accessing https

Comment: Can you share the values file, you've used installing Traefik, if any? Note, your Ingress spec.tls is what you would usually do, with most Ingress Controllers, but with Traefik, you would instead set an annotations, see https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#enabling-tls-via-annotations. Or you could force redirect all http to your https endpoint, and never set those annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Checking Traefik Docs [1], [2]

Setting spec.tls in your Ingress would not be enough for Traefik to serve your application in https. You need to add an annotation:

```
annotations:
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: true
```

Alternatively, if you mean to rewrite all http to https, assuming Traefik Helm Chart, you could set `ports['web'].redirectTo: websecure`.

Traefik is quite different from other Ingress Controllers, as it ships with its own Custom Resource Definitions (IngressRoute, TLSOptions, TLSStores, Middlewares, ...). Your question right now can be dealt with relatively easily without going there. Though you should consider looking into this, as they could be quite helpful, dealing with other basic configurations (headers injection, url rewrites, ...)

[1] https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#enabling-tls-via-annotations

[2] https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#certificates-management

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

my understanding as far as i am not using "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1" i dont need to work with annotations. I want to enable the application by accessing via http and https. Http is working well, https --> 404, but I can see the certificate in Google/Safari Browser and this is valid.

Comment: The annotation I'm talking about applies to the Ingress, as in networking.k8s.io/v1 / v1beta1 . If you don't set it, then Traefik consider you do not want to expose your Ingress using TLS.

Comment: annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure

I added this annotations, still not wirking.

Comment: The ` traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: true` one. The doc is pretty explicit about it, it's really worth reading.